# How can armel linux kernel even boot with armhf rootfs?

Tags: linux, kernel

This might sound stupid, but this question bothers me for a long time.

Everybody knows that armel binary is not compatible with armhf one.

But I can put armel Linux kernel(build from armel cross compiler) and armhf rootfs together; then boot it.

What surprise me is that armel kernel works fine on armhf rootfs; how can it happen? I do search the internet, but no one ever talk about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel doesn't use float. It can use float, but it's handled different, more difficult way than userspace.